# I've been looking for the way to return multiple SQL results with Json format in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-bigquery

I've been looking for the way to output multiple SQL result with Json format in Python3. My API gets request parameters(luid) and passes them to BigQuery in SQL and return the result to client with Json format. So far , I succeeded in building the api that can handle only one parameter but if you put multiple parameters , this api could return only first parameter's result. I'm guessing this problem is occurred by using `return jsonify({request_luid: str(row[0]) })` in outer loop. I have no idea how should I change my code and logic.Could anyone tell me?? I'm welcome to any idea .

```
output of my code 
{
    "XXXXXXX5e30ab17f6b536879d25555": "True"⬅︎My SQL seems work correctly 
}

ideal otput
{
    "XXXXXXX5e30ab17f6b536879d25555": "True",
    "XXXXXXX8r30ab17f6b536879d25555": "False",
    "XXXXXXX9t30ab17f6b536879d25555": "True",
}
```

```
Endpoint

https://test-project-galvanic-ripsaw-281806.df.r.appspot.com?luid=XXXXXXX5e30ab17f6b536879d25555&luid=XXXXXXX8r30ab17f6b536879d25555
&luid=XXXXXXX9t30ab17f6b536879d25555
```

```
main.py

@app.route('/')
def get_request():
    request_luids = request.args.getlist('luid') or ''
    for i in range(len(request_luids)):
        request_luid = request_luids[i]
        client = bigquery.Client()
        query = """SELECT EXISTS(
                     SELECT 1
                     FROM `test-project-281806.hitobito_test.test3` as p
                     WHERE p.luid = '{}'
                     AND p.cv_date IS NOT NULL limit 1000)""".format(request_luid)


        job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
            query_parameters=[
                bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("request_luid", "STRING", request_luid)
            ]
        )

        query_job = client.query(query)
        query_res = query_job.result()


        for row in query_res:
            return jsonify({request_luid: str(row[0]) })


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: why you return the first row of result?

Comment: @Maryam Abdoli you mean this part of code ?? return jsonify({request_luid: str(row[0]) })

Comment: Yes, I think so you return just a row of data! Create a dictionary and push data into it for every row and then return it.

Comment: @ Maryam Abdoli  Thank you so much . maybe I need to make function to make parameters and result dictionary . actually I'm still not clear what should I do next though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
for row in query_res:
    return jsonify({request_luid: str(row[0]) })
```

you can use this piece of code:

```
@app.route('/')
def get_request():
    request_luids = request.args.getlist('luid') or ''
    result = {} # define an empty dictionary for final result

    for i in range(len(request_luids)):
        request_luid = request_luids[i]
        client = bigquery.Client()
        query = """SELECT EXISTS(
                     SELECT 1
                     FROM `test-project-281806.hitobito_test.test3` as p
                     WHERE p.luid = '{}'
                     AND p.cv_date IS NOT NULL limit 1000)""".format(request_luid)


        job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
            query_parameters=[
                bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("request_luid", "STRING", request_luid)
            ]
        )

        query_job = client.query(query)
        query_res = query_job.result()
        # you don't need other rows of result because you return the first element, so break the for loop
        for row in query_res:
            temp_result = jsonify({request_luid: str(row[0]) })
            break

        result.update(temp_result) # add temp_result to the final result 

    # then return the final result
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: thank you so much ! I got big hint from your code. Actually I got another error "'Response' object is not iterable" that's why I changed jsonify to json.dumps and I'm working on ValueError . Maybe I will be able to solve this problem .

Answer (score 0):

My final code is below . Thank you so much for good advice ! Maryam Abdoli

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from google.cloud import bigquery
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def get_request():
    request_luids = request.args.getlist('luid') or ''
    result = {}
    for i in range(len(request_luids)):
        request_luid = str(request_luids[i])
        client = bigquery.Client()
        query = """SELECT EXISTS(
                     SELECT 1
                     FROM `test-project-281806.hitobito_test.test3` as p
                     WHERE p.luid = '{}'
                     AND p.cv_date IS NOT NULL)""".format(request_luid)

    
        job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
            query_parameters=[
                bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("request_luid", "STRING", request_luid)
            ]
        )
    
        query_job = client.query(query)
        query_res = query_job.result()

        for row in query_res:
            temp_result = {request_luid: str(row[0])}
            break

        result.update(temp_result)

    return json.dumps(result) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```